# What resources can teach me to draw floor plans by hand?

Tags: drafting

Are there any simple books or websites that can teach me how to draw floor plans? It seems most planning is done with CAD software. I like the idea of being able to sketch out ideas down on paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drafting "by hand" is still taught in most architecture (and often civil engineering) schools. AutoCAD is simply one tool in the toolbox of a draftsman.

So, I would look for a book on basic architectural drafting. You might see if you can get in touch with the drafting teacher at your local high school or community college and see what he uses as a textbook.

As for being able to "sketch" ideas, only the very roughest plans are drawn freehand. Artist's renderings and some elevation drawings will have an element of freehand to them, but the main lines of the building will be drawn with the paper taped to the drafting table and using a straightedge and speed squares.

Comment: Rough freehand drawing is ok. I've visited my local bookstore and searched online at Amazon but can't find a suitable book.

Answer (score 4):

A site like the following will help you learn the basics:

- [How to Design Your Own House Plans — Free Online Tutorials](http://www.the-house-plans-guide.com/)

Knowing the basics of hand-drafting is a good thing to know (IMHO).

That said, as an ex-heavy user of [Autodesk](http://autodesk.com/) products (at least during this time), I recommend you spend the majority of your time learning a "simple" (and free) CAD/Drawing package, eg

- [New to Google SketchUp](http://sketchup.google.com/training/videos/new_to_gsu.html)
- [Autodesk Homestyler](http://www.homestyler.com/)