# Some Free or Open Source Software To Design Rooms and Working Areas?

Tags: software

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an affordable 2D drafting software for amateurs?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/820/what-is-an-affordable-2d-drafting-software-for-amateurs)

I need time-and-another organize places quickly for projects and I find that some software would be useful to do that automatically. Suppose I have 100 square meters' square and 10 innovators working on the same electronics/hardware/software building project. The area is empty -- and you have budget for tables etc. You want to keep design simple. Is there some software to do that automatically or to help to do that automatically?

I rejected some very high cost package so no such things please. Any open-sourced design thing under the sun?

Comment: Take a look **[here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7908/what-resources-can-teach-me-to-draw-floor-plans-by-hand/7911#7911)**. Is that the kind of thing you're after?

Comment: I'd also suggest http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/820/what-is-an-affordable-2d-drafting-software-for-amateurs